# How to make 1x2 lumber longer?

Tags: wood, furniture, hardwood, lumber, frame

I want to DIY a 99x72 inches rectangle wood frame by 1x2 lumber. The frame is used to keep a pet's playpen in shape, so the dimension is kind of customized.

I found 1x2 lumber in 6 feet and 8 feet lengths, which mean for the longer side. I need 8 feet plus extra 3 inches. Is there any way I can obtain or make this specific length lumber? Thanks.

Comment: Can see if they can order longer pieces or go to a lumber yard.  Can also splice two pieces with another piece.  If just using has a border strength not as important as using it hold something in place.

Comment: Is 99x72 your interior dimension? or your exterior dimension?

Comment: 99x72 is interior dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get some 1.5" x 3" splice plates similar to the ones shown below from Amazon.

[image]

Comment: These are not going to be very rigid. They're not long enough to withstand the strong torque forces at play.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure quite what kind of pets you're keeping in a 99x72" enclosure, but a 1x2 won't have a lot of strength. It's only 3/4" thick on the best days, and if the critters are jumping around (dogs? cats?) they may throw a lot of weight at it and break it. Also, if they try to climb out, they might be able to tip or break something made of that light a construction.

At a minimum, I'd suggest a 50" piece and a 49" piece overlapping a vertical piece. That way, you've at least got vertical support at the ends and in the middle helping to keep the thing in the correct shape.

While you could use 1x2 for the verticals, I'd want to make them out of 1x3 or even 1x4 so that there is plenty of good material to put screws in to hold things together.

Of course, my wife says I overbuild everything. However, things I build do not come apart...

Comment: The playpen is for bunny. It is assembled by clamps and plastic panels, so the connection is soft, and the panel wall is not easy to keep the rectangle shape. The wood frame is only used to hold the panel wall straight and in position.

Comment: Rabbits like to chew @YRJ (ask me how I know...). They'll chew on plastic, rubber, wood, etc. You're going to want a metal cage/pen _much_ sooner rather than later, or you'll discover the rabbit wandering the house instead of in his pen.

Answer (score 4):

How do you get bigger lumber? Buy bigger lumber. In the world of DIY and carpentry in general, smaller boards are made from larger boards as a matter of course.

**A 1x4-10 ripped down the middle** nicely satisfies your request. If you don't have a table saw at your disposal, a circular saw with its rip fence installed will do just fine.

You could also splice two 1x2 boards with a simple long angle miter. A few carefully placed screws and some wood glue would make it about as solid as the rest of the length.

```
_________________________________________
      *   |        
          |*   |
          |    |*
_______________|_____*_____________________
               ^- screws
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 99x72 is your exterior dimension... And assuming your 1x2s are 3/4 x1 1/2...

You can get an exterior dimension of 99x72 by flipping your 1x2s sideways (or using 2x2s instead) and connecting your 6' boards to the ends of your 8' boards... Which would give you an exterior dimension of 99".

[image: 99x72 by connecting the 6 foot boards to the ends of the 8 foot boards]